# Efficiently comparing two large Java lists to find unique items

Tags: java, list, performance, object, comparison

How can I efficiently compare two large lists of objects in Java, and identify the items that are present in one list but not the other?

Example:

Suppose I have two large CSV files containing data for thousands of employees, with columns for name, department, and salary. I need to compare the two files and identify any employees that are present in one file but not the other, based on their name and department.

```java
public static void compareCSVFiles(String file1, String file2) {
    List<Employee> list1 = readCSVFile(file1);
    List<Employee> list2 = readCSVFile(file2);

    List<Employee> uniqueTo1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Employee> uniqueTo2 = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Employee emp1 : list1) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (Employee emp2 : list2) {
            if (emp1.getName().equals(emp2.getName()) && emp1.getDepartment().equals(emp2.getDepartment())) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            uniqueTo1.add(emp1);
        }
    }

    for (Employee emp2 : list2) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (Employee emp1 : list1) {
            if (emp2.getName().equals(emp1.getName()) && emp2.getDepartment().equals(emp1.getDepartment())) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            uniqueTo2.add(emp2);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Employees unique to " + file1 + ":");
    for (Employee emp : uniqueTo1) {
        System.out.println(emp.getName() + " (" + emp.getDepartment() + ")");
    }

    System.out.println("Employees unique to " + file2 + ":");
    for (Employee emp : uniqueTo2) {
        System.out.println(emp.getName() + " (" + emp.getDepartment() + ")");
        }
     }
```

- The code reads the CSV files line-by-line and stores each line as a string. This may not be memory-efficient or scalable for large files.
- code uses nested loops to compare each employee in one list to each employee in the other list, which can be slow and inefficient for large files.
- The code only identifies employees that are unique to one list, but not the other. It does not identify employees that are present in both lists.

I think we can write these codes more efficiently. I want to know your ideas on this.

Comment: edited the question. wanted to get a broader approach to get your ideas. now have an example

Comment: Assuming you can fit everything in memory (or are willing to use some memory in a trade-off for more speed) one would typically build a lookup table using a `HashSet` (or `Map` if you want to do more than just checking for presence) as this will allow efficient lookups in constant time `O(1)`.Then you loop over the other dataset and for each entry there check whether you have an enty with the same identity in your lookup table. All in all this will take you linear time `O(n)` instead of `O(n²)` for the naive double loop approach.

Comment: Like Mushroomator, my first thought was to use a hash to efficiently store and retrieve the data.  `HashSet` has `removeAll()` which implements the asymmetric set difference of two sets, which is what I think you want to find unique entries in either set.  As long as you have only "thousands" of entries and not "millions" you should be able to store the data in memory for most systems.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using lists, use a map with a unique indentifier (example employee ID)
then run the second list/map to see if the first map contains it.

that alone will save you a ton of complexity / time

Answer (score 0):

You can load them into sets (implement hashcode/equals based on the equality criteria) and intersect/diff. This will work if the content fits into memory.
If you want a scalable solution, you can sort them on disk merge sort and scan line-by-line.
And, finally, if you want a truly scalable solution then us Spark.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.  The overhead is not that bad since the removal work is done by the sets which are hashed.

```
List<Employee> list1 = List.of(
        new Employee("John", "Fiance"), 
        new Employee("Mary", "Engineering"), 
        new Employee("John", "Engineering"), 
        new Employee("Linda", "Engineering"), 
        new Employee("Alice", "Personel")); 
List<Employee> list2 = List.of(
        new Employee("John", "Personel"), 
        new Employee("Mary", "Fiance"), 
        new Employee("John", "Engineering"), 
        new Employee("Linda", "Engineering"), 
        new Employee("Alice", "Personel")); 

Set<Employee> uniqueTo1 = new HashSet<>(list1);
Set<Employee> uniqueTo2 = new HashSet<>(list2);

uniqueTo1.removeAll(list2);
uniqueTo2.removeAll(list1);

uniqueTo1.forEach(System.out::println);
System.out.println();
uniqueTo2.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
Employee[getName=Mary, getDepartment=Engineering]
Employee[getName=John, getDepartment=Fiance]

Employee[getName=Mary, getDepartment=Fiance]
Employee[getName=John, getDepartment=Personel]
```

Notes:

- I used a record here to facilitate the demo. `Equals` and `hashCode` must be overridden in your Employee class for this to work.  That would also allow you to compare objects instead of fields.
- If you allow duplicates you must use lists since sets don't permit duplicate entries.
- It would be better to read in at least one list first and then create the exclusion lists  as you read in the second.  This can help avoid list duplication.  But as your lists don't appear to be that large this should not be a problem.

Here is how that might be done.  Presume that `list1` has been read in.

```
Employee emp = null;
List<Employee> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Employee> uniqueTo1 = list1; // could also make a copy
while (reading next of what would be list2) {
    list2.add(emp);
    if (!list1.contains(emp)) {
        uniqueTo2.add(emp); // if not in list1, must be unique to list2
    else {
        list1.remove(emp); //  if it is in list1 it can't be unique so remove it.
    }                      //  list1 is now becoming unique to list1.
}
```